# How to use dist() function to calculate pairwise distances within groups

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the total distance traveled by a specific person, but I'm not sure how to specify it for the dist() function, so that I will get individual's distance, and not everyone's distance all summed up (e.g. John + James + Bob +...'s). The data looks something like this (but lot bigger)

```
Name    x    y
John    12  34
John    15  31
John    8   38
John    20  14
John    12  35
Bob     2   15
Bob     2   18
James   30  21
James   30  28
James   29  32
...
```

My current code is:

```
dist(rbind(data$x,data$y), method = "euclidean").
```

I've tried putting in `if(data$name == "John")` code everywhere possible with {} and what not, but they all seem to give me an error. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Why don't you share part of your data along with your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I'll add it ASAP. It's my first time using this site so might take a while

Comment: With out seeing your data it is a bit tough to tell, but I would guess you need to subset your data frame to have just John's data for example.  'data[data$name ==  "John", ]` then use `dist`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're calculating distance travelled,
then I think you need the distance between contiguous coordinates.
You can use the `dist` function provided by the `proxy` package,
which is a bit more flexible than the default one,
and combine it with `dplyr`:

```
library(proxy)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Name = c(rep("John", 5L), rep("Steve", 5L), rep("Dave", 5L)), 
                 x = sample(1:30, 15L),
                 y = sample(1:30, 15L))

group_fun <- function(sub_df) {
    if (nrow(sub_df) == 1L)
        return(data.frame(Name = sub_df$Name, total = 0))

    x <- sub_df[-nrow(sub_df), c("x", "y")]
    y <- sub_df[-1L, c("x", "y")]
    total <- sum(proxy::dist(x, y, method = "Euclidean", pairwise = TRUE))
    # return
    data.frame(Name = sub_df$Name[1L], total = total)
}

out <- df %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    do(group_fun(.))
```

Inside `group_fun` `x` contains all coordinates except the last one,
and `y` contains all coordinates except the first one
(per group in both cases),
so `x[i,]` and `y[i,]` contain contiguous coordinates for any `i`.
Therefore, when we call `proxy::dist` with `pairwise = TRUE`,
we now get the distance between each pair (row-wise).

In the returned data frame we use `sub_df$Name[1L]` because `Name` was a grouping variable,
so it must be the same for all rows in `sub_df`,
and we only want one of its values in the summary.

And if you want to be a bit more compact you can do it without `dist`
(i.e. only with `dplyr`):

```
out <- df %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarise(total = sum(sqrt((x - lag(x))^2 + (y - lag(y))^2), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I will also try this later and let you know how I go. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` package you can apply the `dist` function over each subset of the `name` varible. The solution is based on the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44395630/3846570).

```
library(dplyr)
data = data.frame(name = c(rep('John',5), rep('Steve', 5), rep('Dave', 5)), x=sample(1:10,15), y=sample(1:10,15))
distout = data %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(distmatrix=dist(rbind(x, y), method = "euclidean"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'll try this as well as subsetting my data as Ian suggested.  I will need some time to research and fully understand the code you have suggested though, because I've just started using R. But I'll definitely give it a go.